# How to atualize and calculate the derivative of the weights and bias of a 3 layer neural network (with only numpy)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to create a 3 layer neural network, with one input layer, one hidden layer and one output layer. The input layer is represented by a `(1, 785)` Numpy array, thinking that I'm classifying digits from 0 to 9 with the MNIST dataset. My forward propagation algorithm has all the dimensions of the arrays right, although, when I compute the derivative of the weights and biases of the network, the shapes of the arrays become different from the originals and, when I do the gradient descent to update the weights and biases, the operation is not possible because, according to the [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), broadcasting is not possible when the shapes are not equal or one of them is equal to 1

Here's the calculation of the derivatives of the weights and biases on the backpropagation:

```py
    def backpropagation(self, x, y):
        predicted_value = self.forward_propagation(x)
        cost_value_derivative = self.loss_function(
                predicted_value.T, self.expected_value(y), derivative=True
            )
        print(f"{'-*-'*15} PREDICTION {'-*-'*15}")
        print(f"Predicted Value: {np.argmax(predicted_value)}")
        print(f"Actual Value: {y}")
        print(f"{'-*-'*15}{'-*-'*19}")

        derivative_W2 = (cost_value_derivative*self.sigmoid(
            self.output_layer_without_activity, derivative=True)
        ).dot(self.hidden_layer.T).T

        print(f"Derivative_W2: {derivative_W2.shape}, weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer: {self.weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape}")
        assert derivative_W2.shape == self.weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape

        derivative_b2 = (cost_value_derivative*(self.sigmoid(
                self.output_layer_without_activity, derivative=True).T
        )).T

        print(f"Derivative_b2: {derivative_b2.shape}, bias_on_output_layer: {self.bias_on_output_layer.shape}")
        assert derivative_b2.shape == self.bias_on_output_layer.shape

        derivative_b1 = cost_value_derivative*self.sigmoid(
            self.output_layer_without_activity.T, derivative=True
        ).dot(self.weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer.T).dot(
            self.sigmoid(self.hidden_layer_without_activity, derivative=True)
        )
        print(f"Derivative_b1: {derivative_b1.shape}, bias_on_hidden_layer: {self.bias_on_hidden_layer.shape}")

        assert derivative_b1.shape == self.bias_on_hidden_layer.shape

        derivative_W1 = cost_value_derivative*self.sigmoid(
            self.output_layer_without_activity.T, derivative=True
        ).dot(self.weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer.T).dot(self.sigmoid(
                self.hidden_layer_without_activity, derivative=True)
        ).dot(x)

        print(f"Derivative_W1: {derivative_W1.shape}, weights_input_layer_to_hidden_layer: {self.weights_input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape}")
        assert derivative_W1.shape == self.weights_input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape

        return derivative_W2, derivative_b2, derivative_W1, derivative_b1
```

And here is the forward propagation that I implemented:

```py
    def forward_propagation(self, x):

        self.hidden_layer_without_activity = self.weights_input_layer_to_hidden_layer.T.dot(x.T) + self.bias_on_hidden_layer

        self.hidden_layer = self.sigmoid(
            self.hidden_layer_without_activity
        )

        self.output_layer_without_activity = self.weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer.T.dot(
            self.hidden_layer
        ) + self.bias_on_output_layer

        self.output_layer = self.sigmoid(
            self.output_layer_without_activity
        )

        return self.output_layer
```

The gradient descent update on the weights and biases, using the `weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer` variable as an example, is `weights_on_hidden_layer_to_output_layer -= learning_rate*derivative_W2`, where `derivative_W2` is the derivative of the loss function in relation to the `weights_hidden_layer_to_output_layer`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not providing the definition of your function, it is hard to know where it went wrong. However, I usually use this code snippet to compute a NN with 1 hidden layer and all sigmoid activation. I hope it help you debug your code.

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # forward propagation
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = Sigmoid(Z2)

    # backward propagation
    dZ2 = A2 - Y
    dW2 = 1/m * np.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
    db2 = 1/m * np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dZ1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2) * (1 - np.power(A1, 2))
    dW1 = 1/m * np.dot(dZ1, X.T)
    db1 = 1/m * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    # update parameters
    W1 = W1 - alpha * dW1
    b1 = b1 - alpha * db1
    W2 = W2 - alpha * dW2
    b2 = b2 - alpha * db2

print(f'W1:{W1} b1:{b1} W2:{W2} b2:{b2}')
```